# How do I apply CSS class on a specific page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, class, custom-post-type

I have 2 Custom Post Types:

- single-actress.php
- single-films.php

I know that can specific CSS class for a page placing in front the file name.
Example:

**.single .nameclass** (and theoretically should only apply in *single.php*)

...but NO!. This also affect in others Custom Post Types what starting with single (single-actress.php & single-films.php)

How can I get **only apply in single.php** (the normal post of Wordpress) and no in the others Custom Post Types?

Comment: can you show your code and explanne better what you want

Comment: .single.whatever will do only both single and whatever in the class

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress if you want to apply css to a specific page.
there is a unique class in every page called **page-id-11**

[image]

[image]

Using this page-id-11 as parent class you can apply css to any page specifically

Hope this helps

Accept as answer if it helps

Comment: I want to apply it to all wordpress posts, it's not a specific page. That's why I've specified the .single in front of the css class.

But as I said it also affects custom post types

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure of the details of your particular situation, but perhaps the css `:not()` pseudo-class would come in handy. Something like

```
.single:not(.one-cpt,.another-cpt) {
```

This might or might help, depending on your theme, your precise goal, etc. Also, having more than one class inside the `:not` might only be supported in Safari, though there might be a jquery workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In your header.php file, modify this line:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

to this:

```
<body <?php body_class('posttype-' . $post->post_type); ?>>
```

This will add a class to the body tag `posttype-abcdef` so you can target it.